# How to replace contents of RDD with another while preserving order?

Tags: apache-spark

I have two RDDs, one `(a, b, a, c, b, c, a)` and the other - a paired RDD `((a, 0), (b, 1), (c, 2))`.

I want to replace the `a`s, `b`s and `c`s in first RDD with 0,1,2 (which are the values of keys a,b,c respectively in second RDD), respectively. I'd like to preserve the order of the events in first RDD.

How to achieve it in Spark?

Comment: #protip: How would you do that in Scala?

Answer (score 5):

For example like this:

```scala
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq("a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "c", "a"))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 0), ("b", 1), ("c", 2)))

rdd1
  .map((_, 1)) // Map first to PairwiseRDD with dummy values
  .join(rdd2)
  .map { case (_, (_, x)) => x } // Drop keys and dummy values
```

If mapping RDD is small it can be faster to `broadcast` and `map`:

```scala
val bd = sc.broadcast(rdd2.collectAsMap)
// This assumes all values are present. If not use get / getOrElse
// or map withDefault
rdd1.map(bd.value)
```

It will also preserve an order of elements.

In case of `join` you can add increasing identifiers (`zipWithIndex` / `zipWithUniqueId`) to be able to restore an initial ordering but it is substantially more expensive.

Comment: Thats right. I did that too, but then again, collectAsMap is very expensive as my rdd is huge. And in the latter case i will have to sort the rdd after zipping with index and joining which would be again, as you said, expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `join`.

First to simulate your `RDDs`:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List("a","b","a","c","b","c","a"))
val mapping = sc.parallelize(List(("a",0),("b",1),("c",2)))
```

You can only join `pairRDDs`, so map the original `rdd` to a `pairRDD`and then join with `mapping`

```
rdd.map(s => (s, None)).join(mapping).map{case(_, (_, intValue)) => intValue}
```